# Sending a email message using app in mailcore xcode:error in text of body of the mail missing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mailcore

This is the implementation file.Mail is sending but the problem is text in the body of mail is missing to the recepient of mail,can any one pls help me......  how to rectify the this issue

```
@implementation MyController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        myMessage = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [myMessage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
    CTCoreMessage *msg = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];
    [msg setTo:[myMessage to]];
    [msg setFrom:[myMessage from]];
    [msg setBody:[myMessage body]];
    [msg setSubject:[myMessage subject]];

    BOOL auth = ([useAuth state] == NSOnState);
    BOOL tls = ([useTLS state] == NSOnState);
    [CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:msg server:[server stringValue] username:[username stringValue]
    password:[password stringValue] port:[port intValue] useTLS:tls useAuth:auth];
    [msg release];
}

- (NSString *)to
{
    return [[[myMessage to] anyObject] email];
}

- (void)setTo:(NSString *)aValue
{
    CTCoreAddress *addr = [CTCoreAddress address];
    [addr setEmail:aValue];
    [myMessage setTo:[NSSet setWithObject:addr]];
}

- (NSString *)from
{
    return [[[myMessage from] anyObject] email];
}

- (void)setFrom:(NSString *)aValue
{
    CTCoreAddress *addr = [CTCoreAddress address];
    [addr setEmail:aValue];
    [addr setName:@""];
    [myMessage setFrom:[NSSet setWithObject:addr]];
}

- (NSString *)subject
{
    return [myMessage subject];
}

- (void)setSubject:(NSString *)aValue
{
    [myMessage setSubject:aValue];
}

- (NSString *)body
{
    return [myMessage body];
}

- (void)setBody:(NSString *)aValue
{
    [myMessage setBody:aValue];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have cyclical references in there, Rehana.

Look at your `setBody` method.

You're trying to set the body of myMessage to the current body of myMessage.  Both of which are NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the values in myMessage object first there is no need to calling the same thing again.
Here how you will do this

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
    //Assuming textfields with the names I have passed as parameter.
    //This is only for demonstration 

    //Set body to myMessage object from textview
    [self setBody:bodytextview.text];
    [self setTo:txtfTo.text];
    [self setFrom:txtfFrom.text];
    [self setSubject:txtfSubject.text];

    BOOL auth = ([useAuth state] == NSOnState);
    BOOL tls = ([useTLS state] == NSOnState);
    //Note I'm passing myMessage Object
    [CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:myMessage server:[server stringValue] username:[username stringValue]
    password:[password stringValue] port:[port intValue] useTLS:tls useAuth:auth];

}
```